# Prove that a given function is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis

We are given the following function :

$g(z)=\sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$ , $(r>0,-\pi <\theta <\pi)$

Also , $g(z)$ is analytic in its domain with derivative : $g^{'}(z)=\dfrac{1}{2g(z)}$

We need to prove that the function composition $G(z)=g(2z-2+i)$ is analytic in the half plane $x>1$ , with derivative $G^{'}(z)=\dfrac{1}{g(2z-2+i)}$ .

What I tried :

We know that the composition of analytic functions is analytic , thus we need to prove that the function , say , $f(z)=2z-2+i$ is analytic ,

Thus , $f(x,y)=2(x-1)+i(2y+1)$ , $u(x,y) = 2(x-2)$ , $v(x,y)=2y+1$ ,

$u_x =2$ , $v_x =0$ , $u_y =0$ , $V_y =2$ , and hence the cauchy riemann equations are satisfied and thus the function seems analytic **"everywhere"** , using the function composition property ..

But we need to prove that the function composition is analytic in the **half plane** $x>1$ only..

What am I doing wrong ?
Could anyone tell ?

Answer (score 1):

Your insight that $f(z) = 2z - 2 + i$ is analytic everywhere is correct. In fact, polynomial functions with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$ help us build up a large class of entire functions. However, while you know that $g\circ f(z) = g(f(z))$ is analytic, you do not yet know where it is analytic. While $f$ is enitre, it moves the half plane 
$$ \mathbb{T} := \lbrace z \in \mathbb{C} \; | \; \Re(z) > 0 \rbrace$$
around a little (although the motion is smooth). Since $g$ is only known to be analytic for complex numbers $z$ with positive modulus that sit in the right half plane, you must prove that whenever $z \in P := \lbrace z \in \mathbb{C} \; | \; \Re(z) > 1 \rbrace$, the equality
$$ f(z) = 2z - 2 +i = \sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}, r > 0, \theta \in (-\pi,\pi)$$
is satisfied.  After you've shown that you can finish the question by taking a routine derivative and remembering to use the chain rule.